# UIActionSheet coming up too far from bottom of screen

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

So for some reason after I've just added an actionsheet it's coming up and stopping above the bottom of the screen. Is there a way to manually tell this where to stop?

```
- (void)showActionSheet:(UIButton *)standardButton{
    UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel Button" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Choose From Library", @"Take Photo", nil];
    popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleAutomatic;
    [popupQuery showInView:self];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        // Choose from library tapped
        NSLog(@"Choose");
    } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        // Take a photo tapped
        NSLog(@"Take");
    } 
}
```

[image]

Comment: [popupQuery showInView:self.view]; instead of  [popupQuery showInView:self];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `self.view` instead of `self`.